# Mathematica ParametricPlot3D: plotting close surfaces

Tags: plotting

I am plotting two surfaces in Mathematica: green and yellow using ParametricPlot3D.
Their intersection is the red curve.

However, in the vicinity of the intersection curve, the colors and meshes mess up.
How to fix it?

Here is my simple code.

```
a = ParametricPlot3D[{3 z^2, (-z^3 + 3 z r), r}, {z, -1.3, 
1.3}, {r, -5, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Green}];

b = ParametricPlot3D[{z, d (z + d^2), -d^2} , {z, -3, 6}, {d, -2, 2}, 
PlotStyle -> {Yellow}];

c = ParametricPlot3D[{3 z^2, -4 z^3 , - z^2}, {z, -1.3, 1.3}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red}];

Show[a,b,c]
```

[image]

Comment: Prior to plots, add `SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 8];`

Comment: @BobHanlon Increasing `PlotPoints` cleans up the colors but not the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

```
SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D,
  PlotPoints -> 200,
  MaxRecursion -> 8,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}];
```

Under `Possible Issues` for `ParametricPlot3D` it states that "Surfaces that have multiple coverings may exhibit unusual behavior". Turning off the `Mesh` for plot `b` avoids the overlapping meshes at the expense of some mesh outside the overlap.

```
a = ParametricPlot3D[
   {3 z^2, (-z^3 + 3 z r), r},
   {z, -13/10, 13/10}, {r, -5, 3},
   PlotStyle -> Green];

b = ParametricPlot3D[
   {z, d (z + d^2), -d^2},
   {z, -3, 6}, {d, -2, 2},
   PlotStyle -> Yellow,
   Mesh -> None];

c = ParametricPlot3D[
   {3 z^2, -4 z^3, -z^2},
   {z, -13/10, 13/10},
   PlotStyle -> Red];

Show[a, b, c]
```

[image]

Comment: Bob, thank you! So, the conclusion is that Mathematica cannot really do that? I guess I could try to use some other program to create such a plot. Any advice?

Comment: I have no recommendations.